# Bootstrap sidebar and content under navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help me with that issue? why my sidebar and content is under my navbar? I tried remove class and make some changes and I have no success.

sidebar and content should be under navbar no?

I know I can create that class insert in the row and fix my problem, but I am trying the solution without create any css or extra class.

```
.margin-top100{
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          project
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
            <li><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <br>link </li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <br>link</li>
            <li>
              <br> Welcome </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-mg-2 col-sm-2"> sidebar </div>
    <div class="col-mg-10 col-sm-10"> content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5zc66j20/

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Bootstrap's documentation on : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top. By default, the navbar is 50px high.

**solution 1:**

```
 body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
```

**solution 2:**

change the class : `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-static-top`

thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/5zc66j20/1/)

just because of the `position` property this problem occurs.
**now the solution is:**

```
.margin-top100{
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

use class `margin-top100` when your content section starts.

Comment: thanks for the help, Gautam, I forgot to mention that in my question, I can use margin-top:100px and will fix my problem, the thing I don't wanna use, I just wanna know what this is happen if I am using bootstrap correctly, understand?

Comment: you are using some disorders when you closing tags near where you close `nav` tag. you should correct that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php) for getting things working

It looks to me like they add padding to the top of the body. I admit that I am not crazy about this answer either. However, if the navbar has `position: fixed;`, there is no way to make other elements automatically flow around it (that is kind of the point of `position: fixed`).